# When I do saveAndFlush on an entity object, I see hibernate generates 2 update queries. Why is it and how to avoid it?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

These are the steps I am doing -
1.Load the entity
2.update few fields on the entity.
3.saveAndFlush

I see one update query with all 3 fields updated in Step#2.
Other update query is updating one of the 3 fields but the value is from Step#1 and not Step#2.

Can someone please help me figure out how to avoid that?

EDIT- Added my classes.

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Enrollment
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Embedded
    private Section sectionInformation = new Section();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TakingExam takingExam;
}
```

```
public ResponseEntity controllerMethod(){
     Enrollment enrollment = service.getEnrollment(enrollmentId);
        if (enrollment == null)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(NOT_FOUND);
        }
        
        Enrollment otherEnrollment = null;
        if (check some condition)
        {
            otherEnrollment = 
               service.getEnrollment(request.someValue());
            validator.validateOtherEnrollment(enrollment, 
               otherEnrollment, request.someValue());
        }
       enrollment.takingExam(request.getTakingExam());
        if (otherEnrollment != null)
        {
            service.swapEnrollments(enrollment, otherEnrollment);
        }
}
```

```
private void swapEnrollments(Enrollment enrollment, String userName){
///lots of validations
    enrollment.setUpdatedBy(userName);
        fromEnrollment.setUpdatedDate(new 
    Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    enrollmentRepo.saveAndFlush(enrollment); ---- THIS IS WHERE I SEE 2 UPDATE QUERIES AS PUT BELOW
}
```

```
update
        enrollment 
    set
        taking_exam=?,
        updated_by=?,
        updated_date=? 
    where
        id=?
```

```
 update
        enrollment 
    set
        taking_exam=? 
    where
```

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible code.

Comment: And the actual SQL statements.

Comment: I am the OP. Please ignore mismatched arguments in the code pasted above. I tried to rename few fields and removed unnecessary content.

Comment: 2nd update query for `@DynamicUpdate`

Comment: Its happening even without @DynamicUpdate. I added that to see what fields are getting updated. WIthout that annotation, I see entire table fields in the sql query.

Comment: You're making some kind of an action which is causing hibernate to `flush()` and cascade an update. You can either disable cascade updates or identify where the flush is occurring and move that to a later point.

Comment: @JohnVint ok, I will try to comment each line and see what's causing the issue. Thanks for giving me the direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening in my code -

1. Load the entity 1
2. Load the entity 2
3. update few fields on the entity 1.
4. update few fields on entity 2
5. saveAndFlush entity 1- This step was creating 2 update queries.

This is what helped avoid intermediate auto flush

1. Load the entity 1
2. Load the entity 2
3. update few fields on the entity 1.
4. saveAndFlush entity 1 -- Only 1 update query generated !!
5. update few fields on entity 2
6. saveAndFlush entity 2